# How to apply a condition to "used range" in whole column as a loop in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am beginner at VBA, I am stuck plz help. In this image(linked at the end of paragraph), I am trying to insert line above the cells which contains different name than the name of upper cell. Plz tell me if there is an easier way to do this or how to apply the given if else condition to whole "G" Column...

[image]

Still I am adding my code below if you don't need the image...

```
Sub ScanColumn()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim varRange As Range
    Dim currentCell As String
    Dim upperCell As String
    Dim emptyCell As String
    
    currentCell = ActiveCell.Value
        
    bottomCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value

    emptyCell = ""
    
    
Dim intResult As Integer
intResult = StrComp(bottomCell, currentCell)

Dim emptyResult As Integer
emptyResult = StrComp(currentCell, emptyCell)



'I want to apply below condition to whole G column in used range

        If emptyResult = 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Select
        
        ElseIf intResult = 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
        Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
        
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand your perspective, so I have added code to the question...plz help me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have, just call the function "evaluateColumn" and pass the parameters, as example the "trial" sub.

```
    Function evaluateColumn(column As String, startRow As Long, wsh As Worksheet)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsh.Range(column & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long: i = startRow
    Do While i < lastRow
        If wsh.Cells(i, column).Value <> wsh.Cells(i + 1, column).Value And wsh.Cells(i, column).Value <> "" And wsh.Cells(i + 1, column).Value <> "" Then
            wsh.Range(column & i + 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            i = i + 1
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
        
End Function

Sub trial()

evaluateColumn "G", 2, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Woohoho, It worked like an amazing thing...I have to say people like you are amazingly Intelligent. I edited my code and it just worked,.but as a beginner, I understand just a little of that. I understand that you are inserting column (column & i + 1) and then shifting down.  but I don't understand this code completely. I hope I will be more familiar with this thing over time, (And It would be in my favour if you can give some basic informative lines for explanation of code as reply of this comment.) I thank you very much for your efforts and a holy gift as your precious time and energy.

Comment: @AkhilHothi As it seems you are happy with this answer, please accept it. Also consider upvoting it if you are impressed by it (which also seems to be the case here)

Comment: I upvoted it and it is recorded but it will be shown when I will be more reputed...Sorry for that... By the way I encountered a new problem. As I use your code, it insert only one cell on the different name, what I am trying to do is to insert whole row upon the cell... Like when we run the code, content present in columns before G or after G remains in same cells. Need your help again...plz save my life... If you can edit it in code also, then it will be nice

Comment: it also needs to be check whether the next row is empty. otherwise it will add an empty line every time the code is run

Comment: @AkhilHothi, just edited to insert entire rows, and the above request to avoid blank cells evaluation.

Comment: @BrunoQuintero it's perfect now. I am so happy you helped me, And now I have better understanding about this syntax. It is all because of your kindness. You are really Awesome. Thank you so vey very much. You are the one who is there to rescue when it comes to vba.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the difference between my answer and the one below, your question isn't entirely clear. My code is an event procedure. It will run automatically, as you select a cell within the used range of column G.

1. If the value of the selected cell is the same as the cell below it the next row's cell will be selected.
2. If there is a value in either of the two cells, a blank row will be inserted and that row's cell selected. (If you want another row enable the row below the insertion.)
3. If either of the above conditions are true, do nothing and proceed with the selection the user made.

In order to let this code work it must be installed in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you want the action. It will ***not*** work if you install it in a standard code module, like *Module1*.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim TriggerRange    As Range
    Dim Off             As Long         ' offset from Target for selection

    ' if more than one cell is selected choose the first cell
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Set Target = ActiveCell
    
    Set TriggerRange = Range(Cells(2, "G"), Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    ' this code will run only if a cell in this range is selected
'     Debug.Print TriggerRange.Address(0, 0)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, TriggerRange) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Target
            If .Value = .Offset(1).Value Then
                Off = 1
            ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Resize(2, 1)) Then
                Rows(.Row).Insert
                ' Off = 1       ' or -1 to change the selection
            End If
            .Offset(Off).Select
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, you have done a lot for me. Honestly, I don't understand many things in code you provided and I don't even know how to use it for my purpose. But It will be helpful for me in future when I will get more understanding for VBA and programming so plz keep this answer on. Also, It can be helpful for others who are better than me but have same query. Again, thank you very much for your time, energy and love.